# Which takes more memory: multiply one variable or increment a second variable?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Playing with Sorting algorithms; here's the first bit:

```
/** Finding if C is the minimum or maximum in a value set*/     
method giveValue(c):
  private value minimum
  private value maximum
  private value average

  if c < minimum
    minimum = c

  if c > maximum
    maximum = c
```

The interesting part is in determining the average...
I made two solutions:

```
/** Detemine the average by maintaining a new variable*/
private variable total
total += c  
count++
average = total/count
```

But I could also do this:

```
/** multiply the average to its previous form.
    (Avoids creating another private variable) */
average * count
count ++
average = (c + average) / count
```

Inevitably, this method only wants to know the minimum, average, and maximum values in a set, which is what got me wondering:

Would it be faster to:

1. Constantly **multiply** a **single** variable?
2. Constantly **add** to a **second** variable?

If it means anything, I'm practicing all of this in Java, so I'm looking from the perspective of maintaining classes.

Comment: These sorts of microoptimizations aren't likely to make a difference in the overall runtime, especially given that the JVM often does on-the-fly optimizations. Is there any reason why you suspect this would matter?

Comment: Random remark: `if c < maximum` should probably be `if c > maximum`

Comment: That said, there is really no point in computing the average at each iteration. That's useless. And you'll lose precision by constantly dividing and multiplying.

Comment: At the machine level, addition is quick as it takes a single machine instruction, whereas multiplication (especially of floats) takes multiple operations. average * count is an integer (we know this) however the result is probably a float, so you'd need to cast to integer to get significant speedup

Comment: @JB Nizet The method I'm building is not made to be iterated like a loop, but called at individual moments, so it must know all three values every time it's run. Should I clarify something like that in the question?
Also, if multiplying and dividing to lose precision, what would that say if both versions inevitably run division?

Comment: You can also not maintain the average variable at all but calculate it at runtime (asuming the total and count vars can hold the intermediate results). This is also less computatioal intensive if you query the average only irregular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with a total is by far best and has also the best precision.

The other solution accumulates floating point imprecision, and does at least one extraneous division or multiplication:

```
++count;
```

and then the following are equivalent

```
average = (c + average * (count - 1)) / count;
average = (c - average + average * count) / count;
average = (c - average) / count + average;
average += (c - average) / count;
```

The last seeming nicest.

Comment: This answer helped me so much!! So assuming I don't mind precision-loss, would I be right to assume that constantly maintaining a fourth variable inevitably wouldn't slow the method down as much as constantly multiplying the original?

Comment: No an extra variable does not cost anything measurable.

Answer (score 0):

At the machine level, addition is quick as it takes a single machine instruction, whereas multiplication (especially of floats) takes multiple operations. `average * count` is an integer (semantically) however the result is a float, so you'd need to cast to integer or suffer an even greater multiplication penalty.

Also in the second version, you're doing `(c + average)` anyway - so there's one more addition to consider there.

As many others have said though - the difference will be very small and probably not worth considering unless you have a speed problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I agree, the difference would inevitably be very small, but what I'm curious about is which approach wins in the long run. So are you saying the machine level addition vs. multiplication factors in even when using primitives like `int` and `float` in java?

Comment: I believe the first one should be faster unconditionally

Comment: I just saw your edit on the `(c + average)` being present in both sections. So would I be right to assume that I **shouldn't** try to run a method with as few private variables as possible?